# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF' using result from WITH

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to put `IF`..`ELSE` as below but getting error message .

Basically, if IncludeInvalidSales is not set I want sub query result to be filtered further.

> "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ListSalesOrders]
    @OrderId char(36),
    @Top int,
    @IncludeInvalidSales bit
AS
    WITH Temp AS    (SELECT TOP (@Top) Id, OrderId, CustomerName, SalesStatus
                    FROM [dbo].[SalesInventory]
                    WHERE OrderId = @OrderId
                    ORDER BY [Id] DESC)


    IF @IncludeInvalidSales = 1
        BEGIN
            SELECT OrderId, CustomerName, SalesStatus
            FROM Temp
            ORDER BY [Id] ASC
        END     
    ELSE
        BEGIN         
            SELECT OrderId, CustomerName, SalesStatus
            FROM Temp
                    WHERE SalesStatus NOT LIKE '%invalid%'
            ORDER BY [Id] ASC
        END
RETURN 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only follow a common table expression with a single INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement, not an IF .. ELSE construction.

> A CTE must be followed by a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE
>   statement that references some or all the CTE columns. A CTE can also
>   be specified in a CREATE VIEW statement as part of the defining SELECT
>   statement of the view.
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

So, if you still want to use your CTE I would change your code to :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ListSalesOrders]
    @OrderId char(36),
    @Top int,
    @IncludeInvalidSales bit
AS
    IF @IncludeInvalidSales = 1
        BEGIN
            WITH Temp AS    (SELECT TOP (@Top) Id, OrderId, CustomerName, SalesStatus
                            FROM [dbo].[SalesInventory]
                            WHERE OrderId = @OrderId
                            ORDER BY [Id] DESC)

            SELECT OrderId, CustomerName, SalesStatus
            FROM Temp
            ORDER BY [Id] ASC
        END     
    ELSE
        BEGIN         
            WITH Temp AS    (SELECT TOP (@Top) Id, OrderId, CustomerName, SalesStatus
                            FROM [dbo].[SalesInventory]
                            WHERE OrderId = @OrderId
                            ORDER BY [Id] DESC)

            SELECT OrderId, CustomerName, SalesStatus
            FROM Temp
                    WHERE SalesStatus NOT LIKE '%invalid%'
            ORDER BY [Id] ASC
        END
RETURN 0
```

You can also replace your CTE with a table variable, so you can still use your logic as intended.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ListSalesOrders]
    @OrderId char(36),
    @Top int,
    @IncludeInvalidSales bit
AS
    DECLARE @Temp TABLE (Id integer, OrderId integer, CustomerName nvarchar(255), SalesStatus integer)

    INSERT INTO @Temp (Id, OrderId, CustomerName, SalesStatus)
           SELECT TOP (@Top) Id, OrderId, CustomerName, SalesStatus
           FROM [dbo].[SalesInventory]
           WHERE OrderId = @OrderId
           ORDER BY [Id] DESC)

    IF @IncludeInvalidSales = 1
        BEGIN  
            SELECT OrderId, CustomerName, SalesStatus
            FROM @Temp
            ORDER BY [Id] ASC
        END     
    ELSE
        BEGIN             
            SELECT OrderId, CustomerName, SalesStatus
            FROM @Temp
            WHERE SalesStatus NOT LIKE '%invalid%'
            ORDER BY [Id] ASC
        END
RETURN 0
```

Comment: I like the first approach but I think `WHERE SalesStatus NOT LIKE '%invalid%'` should be part of the first query itself when `Temp` is set. Otherwise it will not work in cases where two records exist where the last one inserted was `invalid` sale and the first one was valid. With `Top = 1` and `IncludeValidSales = false` it will not return anything when I am expecting it to return the first one.

Comment: @FrankQ. The accidental filtering you are talking about, is completely avoided if the CTE is only filtered by order number, and the final `SELECT` takes care of the invalid sales filter... without introducing additional logic.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to the provided answer by @marcguillot, which leaves you with one final `SELECT` statement, rather than two.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ListSalesOrders]
    @OrderId char(36),
    @Top int,
    @IncludeInvalidSales bit
AS
    WITH Temp AS (SELECT TOP (@Top) Id, OrderId, CustomerName, SalesStatus
                    FROM [dbo].[SalesInventory]
                    WHERE OrderId = @OrderId
                    ORDER BY [Id] DESC)
    SELECT OrderId, CustomerName, SalesStatus
    FROM Temp
    WHERE
        @IncludeInvalidSales = 1 
        OR SalesStatus NOT LIKE '%invalid%'
    ORDER BY [Id] ASC
RETURN 0
```

**EDIT**

The case where the top `@Top` orders include one or more invalid orders, would leave you with potentially less records than you want, when you filter out the invalid ones. This is avoided by moving the filter logic into the CTE.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ListSalesOrders]
    @OrderId char(36),
    @Top int,
    @IncludeInvalidSales bit
AS
    WITH Temp AS 
        (SELECT TOP (@Top) Id, OrderId, CustomerName, SalesStatus
         FROM [dbo].[SalesInventory]
         WHERE OrderId = @OrderId
             AND (@IncludeInvalidSales = 1 
                  OR SalesStatus NOT LIKE '%invalid%')
         ORDER BY [Id] DESC)
    SELECT OrderId, CustomerName, SalesStatus
    FROM Temp
    ORDER BY [Id] ASC
RETURN 0
```